# How to convert a double array to an integer array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

I have an array that is made up doubles which I need to round down and convert to integers so I can use them as indices in an output array. I have just started `C` programming and am not sure how this works. So far the best I have been able to come up with is:

```
int create_hist( double input_array[], int count, int output_array[17] ) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ ) {
        input_array[i] = int floor(input_array[i]);
        output_array[input_array[i]]++;
```

However I am getting the following errors which I am having trouble deciphering:

```
array.c:11:20: error: expected expression before ‘int’
   input_array[i] = int floor(input_array[i]);
                    ^
array.c:12:7: error: array subscript is not an integer
   hist[input_array[i]]++;
       ^
array.c:14:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
 }
 ^
```

If someone could let me know where I have gone wrong it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to use parentheses to cast, you can't use a `float` as an array index, and your function is defined as returning `int` but never returns anything.

Comment: `int index = input_array[i]` will implicitly convert the `double` to an `int`. No need for casting, or the `floor` function.

Comment: Do not forget to accept one of the answers

Answer (score 4):

Unless you actually want to modify `input_array`, you would be best off saving the rounded off double in an intermediate variable to then access your integer array.  And no need to use `floor()` casting the `double` to `int` will do that.

```
int create_hist(double input_array[], int count, int output_array[17]) {


    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int index = (int)input_array[i];

        if ((index > 16) || (index < 0)) {
            return -1;
        }

        output_array[index]++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Of course, you should really pass in the size of `output_array` as a variable as well, instead of hard-coding it.

Comment: Thank you, that is similar to what I got in the end but I forgot to return 0. It seems to be working now.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to check whether the double values was greater or lesser than `INT_MAX`  and `INT_MIN` before assigning to the `int` array. May not be an issue with the value ranges you are working with, but a `double` can easily overflow and `int` value.

Answer (score 3):

So let get cracking:

First error is due to the fact that you are kind of declaring a function.

```
input_array[i] = int floor(input_array[i]);
```

notice `int` in front of floor, that is not necessary. It should be

```
input_array[i] = floor(input_array[i]);
```

Second error is due to the fact that you are accessing array element using `double` in

```
output_array[input_array[i]]++;
```

either you should do it some other way or do following:

```
output_array[(int) input_array[i]]++;
```

and the third error is unbalanced parenthesizes.